# How can I move a bunch of textframes in VBA in MS Publisher?

Tags: vba, ms-publisher

Is there an easy method which could change the position (horizontal and vertical) of lots of textframes in MS Publisher? And where can I find all the methods with explanations for programming Macros?

Answer (score 0):

The Publisher object model is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff939040.aspx .

Information about the VBA editor (which works the same in Publisher as in Word or Excel), is available here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-Help-on-using-the-Visual-Basic-Editor-61404b99-84af-4aa3-b1ca-465bc4f45432

This moves all selected shapes 2 cm downwards and 3 cm rightwards:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveTextFrames()
    Dim oShapes As ShapeRange
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim moveRight As Long
    Dim moveDown As Long

    moveRight = 3
    moveDown = 2

    Set oShapes = Selection.ShapeRange

    For Each oShape In oShapes
        oShape.Left = oShape.Left + CentimetersToPoints(moveRight)
        oShape.Top = oShape.Top + CentimetersToPoints(moveDown)
    Next oShape

End Sub
```

Just edit these lines if you want some other values:

```
    moveRight = 3
    moveDown = 2
```